# validator function runs on textfield creation, is this normal?

Tags: validation, extjs

i have a validation function called validate
And a textfield with this configuration

```
{
     xtype: 'textfield',
     fieldLabel: 'Normal field',
     name: 'obra_social',
     allowBlank: false,
     validator: validate,
}
```

I expected the validation funciton to run after the textfield value changes
but it executes on page load, i mean when the textfield is rendered.
is this the normal behavior, what am i missing?

thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like normal behavior to me.  I'd recommend using FireBug and placing a breakpoint in your custom function, then look at the stacktrace to see if you can determine why the validator is being called.  What you might find is that you are setting a value on the field, or programmatically blurring the field, triggering the validator.  You can try `setRawValue` if you want to set a value without triggering validation.